# How do I get email faster on exchange server

Tags: email, exchange-server

An email is sent to my mail box. The email contains large attachments.
It take some time before the email actually appear in my mailbox.

Is there a way to know before about this email? Get a notification it is coming? I need just headers and body

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is downloading headers only. You can configure this for all emails, or only emails that are greater than some predetermined file size.

1. On the **Send / Receive** tab, in the **Send & Receive** group, choose **Send/Receive Groups**
2. In the **Send/Receive Group** list, choose **Define Send/Receive Groups...** (or press Ctrl+Alt+S)
3. Select a group to modify and click **Edit...**
4. From the **Accounts** section on the left side of the dialog box, you can select the mail account that you want to modify the settings for.
5. Select a folder from the list of folders in the **Folder Options** section and then choose the option Download headers only.

It is possible to have different setting for different folders, so you could set Outlook to download only headers in a folder that you know gets large email attachments.

Comment: 10x for the quick response. 
Will this include also the body of the email?

Comment: This specifically excludes the body as it's not part of the headers.